# Timber Twig get the filesize of a file from ACF field

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have an ACF field that is a file upload. I am able to get the attachment ID. However in my twig template I am not able to output the filesize as this is not available via ACF.

There is a function I have found:

```
$context['filesize'] = (filesize( get_attached_file(the_attachment_id_here))/1000 );
```

but what I really need it for it to be in twig loop.

I have tried in my template:

```
 {% for item in posts %} 
{{function(filesize( get_attached_file(item.get_field('pdf').id))/1000 )}}
{% endfor %
```

but it returns an error filesize unknown function.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooof, that's a nasty one —

### the *real* best way would be...

First make a custom class for your Posts. Add a method to do the fetching and converting you're looking for ...

```
class MyPost extends \Timber\Post {

  function pdf_filesize() {
    $pdf = $this->get_field('pdf');
    //you may need to convert the value of $pdf into an array...
    $file = get_attached_file($pdf['id']);
    return filesize($file) / 1000;
  }
}
```

And then anywhere you're fetching posts, use `MyPost` instead...

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(null, 'MyPost');
```

In the Twig file...

```
{% for post in posts %}
  File size is {{ post.pdf_filesize }}
{% endfor %}
```

### If you just need to hack it...

```
{% for item in posts %} 
    {{ function(
          'filesize', function(
              'get_attached_file', item.get_field('pdf').id
           )
        ) / 1000 }}
{% endfor % }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jared! Really appreciate you taking the time to answer this. I used the hack version but will try your recommended version as nice to learn how this works

Answer (score 1):

A `var_dump` shows that filesize is a

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $file );
echo '</pre>';
```

to output the filesize

```
$file = get_field('file'); 
$filesize = $file['filesize'];
$filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);
```